# Jenkins and gradle - build projects with latest versions of dependencies for CI, specific versions for production

Tags: jenkins, gradle, ivy

I am working with Jenkins, Gradle and our Ivy repository.

Our build scripts specify the exact version of dependencies to be used for the build. This is good practice for production.

For CI it would be interesting if the project build used the latest versions of our own libraries, that way we could not only see if library changes "broke the build" for the library but also if they broke the projects that use them. That seems to be the point of "integration"!

I understand that gradle will take `"1.+"` instead of `"1.2.3"` so I could hack the build.gradle for the project on the CI server to achieve this. But perhaps there is a neater way to do it (build script recognises it is in CI mode and uses latest and not specific versions, perhaps by running a sed script on `build.gradle` to change it).

Am I missing something in Jenkins or gradle? Are there any gradle plugins that achieve this, or alternative approaches that you have used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something alike this might work with Jenkins:

```
if(System.getenv("BUILD_EXPERIMENTAL") == null) {

    // known to be stable versions       
    apply from: "dependencies.gradle"

} else {

    // bleeding edge versions 
    apply from: "experimental.gradle"

}
```

this just would need the same project being set up twice, once with and once without environmental variable `BUILD_EXPERIMENTAL`, which is used to control which `dependencies` block is being applied.

in case you want it generally being applied, when the project is being built with Jenkins, just replace `BUILD_EXPERIMENTAL` with `BUILD_NUMBER` (which  by default is being set up in that environment).

Comment: This idea would allow the build script to be common for production and CI, which is what I was after. If we use `latest` as suggested by @cantSleepNow in the `experimental.gradle` file then that file wouldn't need any changes for trivial updates and would automatically pick up the new version of our library in a Jenkins build that could be kicked off as a result of building that library.

Comment: @KevinSadler one could as well as have one single `dependencies` block, while loading version-number variables from two different `version.properties` files. my intention was just to have some kind of strict separation between the two environment, therefore the suggestion of two files; which could also be compared with `diff`. the downside of `latest` might be lack of control, while with static version numbers, the IDE will mark outdated versions with a yellowish background, which ensures it is reproducible at any time - and one can see what to update. works with `.gradle` not `.properties`.

Comment: one could even extend this further, with two different `applicationidSuffix`, just to be certain that the resulting package cannot be that easily confused and also, to make manual A/B testing on the same device easier - or locally run `export BUILD_EXPERIMENTAL=1`, in order to build the experimental version.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because the logic, and the `BUILD_NUMBER` tip formed the basis of my own solution. my own answer goes through the solution with tested example code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the latest you can simply use `latest`, or if it's easier something like `[1.0,)` that would match all versions greater or equal to 1.0 (assuming that 1.0 is your "smallest version ever") Look [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision) for other matching patterns, which you could also combing with [statuses](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/settings/statuses.html).

Another way would be to have a local filesystem ivy repo only on the jenkins slave, which would have all the latest versions of your libraries, the point is that this repo is not accessible from developers workstations/laptops/VMs. And then you just simply use that in gradle settings in some way (for example have an environment variable defined only on the jenkins slave). This means that you don't need to change `build.gradle`

Comment: As I don't necessarily want the production builds to use `latest`, or other non-specific options, the first suggestion would force slightly different build scripts to be required for CI and production. However if this was combined with the logic in @Martin Zeitler's answer - and use `latest` in the `experimental.gradle` file we might have something.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leveraging Gradle [dependency locking](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/dependency_locking.html) for achieving this.

- In the build, you would use [dynamic versions](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules) for your dependencies, locked to a good known state.
- Developers and production build would then get these locked versions resolved.
- On CI you could have a (set of) dedicated job(s) that runs and [updates the lock state](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/dependency_locking.html#selectively_updating_lock_state_entries) for one or more modules at a time. Based on that feedback, you could even commit this dependency upgrade or at least open a pull request for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own answer inspired by @Martin Zeitler's answer.

We have a generic build script that get applied to all project `build.gradle` setting up common options, settings and tasks. We want to add in this logic, but make it optional and not break existing build scripts.

The logic will be activated and controlled by a property `project.ext.buildJenkinsWithLatest` which is `true` or `false`.

When the logic is active dependencies from the project files `dependencies-production.gradle` or `dependencies-jenkins.gradle` will be used. The Jenkins dependencies will only be used if the property is true and the CI environment is detected through the presence of the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable.

The generic build script contains this:

```
if (project.ext.has('buildJenkinsWithLatest')) {
    println "Using conditional dependency management..."
    //BUILD_NUMBER is not null if this is a Jenkins build
    if(project.ext.buildJenkinsWithLatest == true && System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") != null) {
        println "--- Using alternative dependencies..."
        apply from: "dependencies-jenkins.gradle"
    }
    else {
        println "--- Using production dependencies..."
        apply from: "dependencies-production.gradle"
    }
}
else {
    println "Conditional dependency management is not active"
}
```

Now any project's `build.gradle` that already applies this script will print this when run:

`Conditional dependency management is not active`

To use the feature we will need to do the following for our project:

1. Create a `dependencies-jenkins.gradle` that contains a `dependencies {}` clause for the libraries we want to select a version dynamically.
2. Create a `dependencies-production.gradle` that contains a `dependencies {}` clause for those libraries, but with a specific version given.
3. Remove the libraries from any `dependencies {}` that remains in the project `build.gradle`.
4. Set the property `project.ext.buildJenkinsWithLatest` to `true` or `false`.
5. Apply the generic build script (after setting the property!).

For example in `dependencies-jenkins.gradle` use the latest 2.x.x version:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'example:my-library:2+'
}
```

As to how to specify the versions in a dynamic way see @CantSleepNow's answer.

And in `dependencies-production.gradle` use a specific version:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'example:my-library:2.3.4'
}
```

Then within `build.gradle` set the property and apply the generic build script:

```
...

project.ext.buildJenkinsWithLatest = true;
apply from: '../bxgradle/bx-std.gradle'

...
```

Now when the build is run on Jenkins the alternative dependencies will be used. Should one wish to build it on Jenkins with the production dependencies then set `project.ext.buildJenkinsWithLatest` to `false`.